# phone call in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

Currently, I found Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls API. unable to make a call or launch different options available to make a call from my app.
And also I try this Code but still can't implement the Phone call function, any solutions for UWP? Thank You.

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract", 1,0))
{
    PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("0213132131", "my name");
}
```

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you if you set a breakpoint on the `if` statement? Is the block entered? If not, then `IsApiContractPresent` returned false.

Answer (score 5):

I've come with a solution that is working on emulator, I cannot test it on actual device, cause I don't own one.

```
PhoneCallStore PhoneCallStore = await PhoneCallManager.RequestStoreAsync();
Guid LineGuid = await PhoneCallStore.GetDefaultLineAsync();

PhoneLine = await PhoneLine.FromIdAsync(LineGuid);
PhoneLine.Dial(phoneNumber, nameToBeDisplayed);
```

You have to add `Windows Mobile Extentions for UWP` to references of your project as well as declare `PhoneCall` capability in app manifest.

Comment: It works on actual device. However, do remember to add PhoneCall in manifest capabilities, otherwise it will crash

Answer (score 3):

The line,

```
PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("0213132131", "my name");
```

only shows the Call UI. It doesn't make a phone call.

You should use `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLine.Dial` to make a phone call. See this for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phoneline.aspx

See this example https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/PhoneCall/cs/Helpers/CallingInfo.cs#L85

Comment: Hi I'm just checking Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLine but it seems that Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls namespace does not contain definition of PhoneLine

Comment: @miskohut Please check if you have included **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP** because Phone call is device specific. Possible duplicate [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824967/uwp-class-phoneline-not-found)