# How to call methods from UWP Phone Calling API

Tags: c#, uwp

How to call methods from UWP Phone Calling API. I want to make a simple uwp phone calling application which just makes a call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704341/phone-call-in-windows-10-uwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704341/phone-call-in-windows-10-uwp)

Comment: Please have more info. What have you tried? researched? what worked? what didn't?

Answer (score 0):

See PhoneCall UWP sample from Microsoft . This is a Mobile only sample : 
[Phone call sample by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall)